# Will eclipse gemini continue on developing

Tags: eclipse, spring, eclipse-gemini

This might sound bit silly, but the project looks really passive and dead, judging only on their website. 
Spring apparently gave up on this project and just passed it to Eclipse foundation. And now Eclipse looks like not doing anything to bring it to the next level.
I'm planning on to split my spring web app into a separate modules, but I seriously don't know if I should go with this project. I'm worried that I'm heading the wrong direction. 
If anybody has an opinion about Eclipse Gemini, please let me know

Comment: Eclipse still need volunteers  to actually work on the code.  Aparently none stepped up.